# Testbench problems

Tags: verilog

So I'm still learning test benches and this one is stumping me.  I wrote a module to do 32bit multiplication and was able to get a testbench working.  I then tried a simple conversion to make the module handle addition/subtraction and modified the test bench.  For some reason the output from the module is coming back an 'x' but I can't see the bug.  Help would be appreciated.

The module does sum & diff (2s complement subtraction) with no overflow, so I just pass the last 32 bits along.

I'm running this under VCS 2014.12 with the following options: -timescale=1ns/1ns +vcs+flush+all +warn=all -sverilog

```
module address_sum_diff(i_Aj, i_Ak, i_Instr, clk, o_Ai);
parameter size = 32; //Size is the width of adder
parameter level = 3; //Number of pipeline stages

input wire[size-1:0] i_Aj; //Aj wire
input wire[size-1:0] i_Ak; //Ak wire
input wire[6:0] i_Instr;   //Instr wire
input wire clk;            //Clock signal

output reg[size-1:0] o_Ai; //Ai register (No Overflow)

reg [size-1:0] Aj_int;            //Aj temp register
reg [size-1:0] Ak_int;            //Ak temp register
reg [6:0] Instr_int;              //Instr temp register
reg [size-1:0] Ai_int[level:1];   //Ai temp register
integer iCount;                   //Temp counter

assign o_Ai = Ai_int[level-1][31:0];//Move LSB only

always @(posedge clk)
 begin
  // Registering input of the adder
  Aj_int <= i_Aj;
  Ak_int <= i_Ak;
  Instr_int <= i_Instr;
  case(Instr_int[6:0])
   7'o020:Ai_int[0] <= Ak_int[size-1:0] + Aj_int[size-1:0];          //addition
   7'o021:Ai_int[0] <= Aj_int[size-1:0] + ~Ak_int[size-1:0] + 32'b1; //two's complement subtraction
  endcase
  // 'level' levels of registers to be inferred at the output of the multiplier
  for(iCount=1;iCount<level;iCount =iCount +1)
   Ai_int [iCount] <= Ai_int [iCount-1];
  end

   endmodule
```

The test bench is as follows

```
//Test Bench
module address_sum_diff_tb;
 parameter size = 32; //Width of adder
 parameter level = 3; //Stages in the pipelined adder

 reg [31:0] i_Aj;  //Aj register (input)
 reg [31:0] i_Ak;  //Ak register (input)
 reg [6:0] i_Instr;//Instr register (input) 

 reg clk;          //Clock signal (input)
 wire [31:0] o_Ai; //Ai register (output)

 //Temp registers & variables
 reg [31:0] Aj_temp [level:0];   //Aj temp register array
 reg [31:0] Ak_temp [level:0];   //Ak temp register array
 reg [31:0] Ai_temp [level:0];   //Ai temp register array
 reg [6:0] Instr_temp [level:0]; //Instr temp register array
 real i; //Temp counter
 real j; //Temp counter
 int k; //Temp counter

 //Initialize values
 initial begin
  clk <= 1'b0;
  i_Aj <= 32'b0;
  i_Ak <= 32'b0;
  i_Instr <= 7'b0;
 end

 //Cycle through all test cases
 always @(posedge clk)
  begin   
   i_Instr <=7'o020;
   for (i=1;i<15;i=i+1)
    begin
     for (j=1;j<15;j=j+1)
      begin
       i_Aj <= i;
       i_Ak <= j;
       Aj_temp[0] <= i_Aj;
       Ak_temp[0] <= i_Ak;          
       Instr_temp[0] <= i_Instr;
       @(posedge clk);
       for(k=1;k<level+1;k=k+1) 
        begin
         Instr_temp[k] <= Instr_temp[k-1];
         Aj_temp[k] <= Aj_temp [k-1];
         Ak_temp[k] <= Ak_temp [k-1];
         Ai_temp[k] <= Aj_temp [k-1] + Ak_temp [k-1];
        end
      end
    end
    $finish;
  end

 //Generate clock 
 always #1 clk <= ~clk;

 //Alert on self-check error
 always @(Ai_temp[level])
  begin
    if (o_Ai!==Ai_temp[level])
    begin
      $monitor("ERROR: %0d,\t%0o,\t%0d,\t%0d,\t%0d,\t%0d",$time, Instr_temp[level],Aj_temp[level], Ak_temp[level], o_Ai, Ai_temp[level]);
    end
  end

 //Log output 
 initial begin
  $dumpfile ("dump.vcd"); 
  $dumpvars; 
 end 

 //Output data to terminal     
  initial begin
    $display("\t\ttime,\tInstr,\tAj,\tAk,\tAi\tAiTmp"); 
    $monitor("%d,\t%0o,\t%0d,\t%0d,\t%0d,\t%0d",$time, Instr_temp[level], Aj_temp[level], Ak_temp[level], o_Ai, Ai_temp[level]); 
  end 

 //Initialize DUT
 address_sum_diff test_address_sum_diff (i_Aj, i_Ak, i_Instr, clk, o_Ai);
endmodule
```

Comment: Any particular reason you are using ```real``` for ```i``` and ```j``` in the testbench?

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but a comment: I think you misunderstand the $monitor statement.  You shouldn't need to put it in an always block with an if check around it.  Use $display or $strobe there instead.

Comment: @bill I usually use $display and do be honest I don't recall why I have $monitor there.  I think I was properly using it, but then wanted to do some auto checking and wrapped it in the if statement without changing it.

Comment: @Tom, yes originally I had an integer but I needed to put 2^32 -1 in the value and int is signed.  I tried using Int unsigned, but for some reason VCS didn't seem to care and still treated it as signed so switching to real let me get 2^32-1 in the loop without any issue.  Seems like a quirk in VCS with the signed/unsigned int.  I'm pretty sure I was using the notation correctly... just wasn't working.

Comment: just stick ```reg [31:0]```, that will get you the required range.

Comment: @tom that causes an error around incompatible types, I think if I go reg [31:0], then I have to change my loops to something like 32'hffffffff.

Answer (score 1):

Found it, bug was in the verilog.

```
reg [size-1:0] Ai_int[level:1];   //Ai temp register
```

I was assigning to `Ai_int[0]`. The line should be:

```
reg [size-1:0] Ai_int[level:0];   //Ai temp register
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are updating Ai_int multiple times in the same always block , so it is taking the updated value, i.e don't use for loop and also there is no such memory like Ai_int[0] as you have declared it as [3:1].